# Locate elements on the page using jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-inspector

I am currently using (e.g.) this in the console

```
> $("input[type='text']").css("background", "purple")
```

to highlight matched elements.  However, this doesn't work well when those elements are hidden.  Is there a good way of doing it?

**EDIT: TO CLARIFY**, I am only using the `input` tag as an example, and when I mean hidden I am talking about an element where it could be outside of the window, inside a hidden container, height 0, or whatever hard to find.  Generally not visible basically, not just `display: none;`.

My concern is to **locate** all the matched elements for development purposes.  This question is *not* about how to make something purple!

Comment: Like `$("input[type='text']").show().css("background", "purple")` ?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit No, I mean more if these elements are inside another container that is hidden.

Comment: @Sarke, what do you mean by hidden? If its `type="hidden"` then change your selector to reflect that, otherwise it shouldnt make a difference if the elements are hidden with css, jQuery will still pick them up

Comment: @AmmarCSE I am talking about any none visible elements, not just those with `display: none;`. For example, it could be outside of the window, inside a hidden container, or height 0.

Comment: @Sarke, none of that matters, the jQuery selector would still acquire them unless they are in a seperate `iframe`. Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: @AmmarCSE I can select them fine, that's not the issue.  I simply want to track down and locate all the usages on the page.

Comment: @Sarke, *locate?* Do you want their x/y coordeinates or the number of times they occur or what?

Comment: @AmmarCSE Yes, locate.  X/Y works or whatever.  Another way to put it, "Chrome: show me all the <p> tags on this page."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86733/discussion-between-ammarcse-and-sarke).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like that:

```
$("input[type='text'], input[type='hidden']").css("background", "purple")
```

Comment: I did not mean that I am having trouble selecting the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could show the hidden elements before trying to change the background.

```
$("input[type='text']").show();
$("input[type='text']").css("background", "purple")
```

If the parent is hidden, show the parent first, then change the background color.

```
$("input[type='text']").parent().show();
$("input[type='text']").css("background", "purple")
```

Comment: I am talking about any none visible elements, not just those with `display: none;`.  For example, it could be outside of the window, inside a hidden container, or height 0.

Comment: Height == 0 is different than being invisible.

Comment: Yes, and I never said "invisible".  The question is to locate matched elements.

Comment: "Not visible" literally means invisible which is in your question.  Do you want to check for visibility, height == 0, or both?

Comment: Do you want to check for visibility, height == 0, or both?

Comment: I don't want to check or select, I want to locate where on the page all the results of the selector are.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$("input[type='text'], input[type='text']:hidden").
    show().
    css("background", "purple");
```